# relationship between ACM curriculum guidelines from 2013 and computing curricula 2020

Tags: curriculum-design, acm

I have been working with the ACM Curriculum Guidelines for proposing courses and topics related to CS in the Faculty that I am currently working on. The core document that we have been using was the ACM Computing Curricular Guidelines from 2013. At the beginning of this year, it emerged the ACM Computing Curricula 2020, which I believe is an improvement over the original document from ACM circa 2005, which defined the guidelines of CS-related careers. The document can be found on:

https://cc2020.nsparc.msstate.edu/

Here I have some doubts about this initial draft. I have seen that (in my personal opinion) it is a little bit awkward. It mentions the different "flavors" of CS worldwide, and then it shows some tools that could be used to measure to see how much CS one career has, even though it does not mention where and how to use these tools. The nice thing about this document is that it contains a set of competencies that should be attained from each undergraduate CS-related field, which, by the way, vaguely reminds me of the ABET competencies system. However, I miss the style of the Curriculum Guidelines of 2013; in which there were recommendations on how to distribute the Body of Knowledge into different Knowledge Areas. Also, even it gave a summary of the recommended topics in each Tier (core or elective).

In summary, I would like to know if one should use this document of 2020 in conjunction with the document that appeared in 2013. Maybe is that ACM will develop another document as an upgrade to the 2013 curriculum guidelines? Any comments or suggestions on how to use this new ACM CS 2020 guidelines?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Actually, since it is a draft report, you have an opportunity to influence the final version. Contact one or both of the Co-chairs. They can also give you some more information on their thinking. I'm not personally involved in this, but know several of the participants. They are likely to be helpful.